# Client-side, how to trust self-signed certificates from an IoT device?

Tags: javascript, react-native, iot

I have an Expo app that works alongside an IoT device.
To connect to that device, the user goes on the device's wifi and sends it info about their wifi so that the device itself can connect to the wifi.

So far, that network call from device to app has been done using fetch to send a post to the IP address of the device, on a specific port. For example http://192.168.1.1:1234/

The team handling the device production has recently added SSL to this call, and now the network call should be made to https://192.168.1.1:1234/. They asked me to "Create a custom "TrustManager" and trust the self-signed certificate I have created."

The problem is that I can't find any information as to how I should trust the self-signed certificate using React Native. I can't even find a way to disable SSL certificate check just for testing purposes (which I can do with Postman for example and the network call works). I'm not even sure which direction to look into as most if not all info I found was specific to node and not client side.

As most of my expertise is in app building, I'm not that knowledgeable in regards to SSL certificates and I'm aware that maybe my comprehension of the problem is wrong and that I may be approaching it from the wrong side.

EDIT : This can't be done via Expo yet, but feel free to upvote the issue [here](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/ssl-pinning)

Comment: You need certificate pinning, look here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with IOT devices as such on React native, but I faced a similar problem when the APIs made didn't have the SSL certification done properly. I solved it by bypassing the SSL certification by using rn-fetch-blob (https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob).

You can try calling the API using rn-fetch-blob like this

```
RNFetchBlob.config({ trusty: true })
.fetch(
'POST',
'https://yourAPI',
{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
dataObj
)
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yeah I had seen this answer while searching, but I was kinda hoping for something I can use without ejecting from Expo.. even though I'm pretty sure it didn't exist for now. Thanks :)

Comment: If you feel this was correct please mark it as correct?